# Use expansion globs {a..z..2} in zsh like in bash

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, wildcards, globbing

Both in `zsh` and `bash` you can:

```
> echo {1..10}
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

> echo {a..z}
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z

> echo {1..10..2} #range 1 to 10 in steps of 2 (i.e. skipping 1)
1 3 5 7 9
```

But in modern `bash` (tested in v5.x) you can:

```
> echo {a..z..3} # a through z chars, but in steps of 3
a d g j m p s v y
```

While in `zsh` (tested in v5.7 and v5.8) I'm getting:

```
> echo {a..z..3} # no globbing will happen                                                                                           
{a..z..3}
```

How can I get the `bash` behavior in `zsh` for expanding a letter range?
Are there any settings in `zsh` to enable this?